# Powershell select most recent file containing a specific string

Tags: powershell

I have written a code in `powershell` that selects the most recent file in a directory.

```
$first = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$first.name
```

However, I need to select the most recent file containing a specific string in the name. How can I adapt my code in order to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work using this:

```
$filterIRP1064="IRP_1064*"
$latest1064 = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filterIRP1064 | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest1064.name
```

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Hoffmann

Like this?

```
$first = Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "stringhere" | group path | select name
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$first.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String -pattern "stringhere" | group path | select name
```

Use this to get all the files containing your string. Select the most recent one afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -path $dir | Select-String -pattern "stringhere" | group path | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | select name
```

This should work...